# How to netboot a Raspberry Pi with TFTP and NFS on a Synology NAS?

Tags: boot, nas, raspberry-pi, nfs, ubuntu-20.04

I can netboot Ubuntu 20.04 on a Raspberry Pi 4b over NFS, using a Synology DS 1618+ as a TFTP and NFS server. But I would like to protect the root file system with `overlayroot` so several machines can run simultaneously from the same root. This just will not work for me. I asked a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1401854/why-doesnt-overlayroot-work-properly-with-a-net-booted-nfs-root-on-a-rpi4) a few days ago on Ask Ubuntu but haven't really received any useful insights. I also understand more about the problem now and would like to rephrase the question here for a broader audience.

## The Problem

Although I can netboot Ubuntu 20.04 on an RPi4 using NFS, as soon as I enable `overlayroot` (`overlayroot="tmpfs:recurse=0"`) the system starts up in a `degraded` state (`systemctl is-system-running`). It seems clear that this has *something* to do with `overlayroot`.

In this state, only `root` can log in. No other users get past the login/password prompt.

Examination of `syslog` reveals that the first thing to go wrong during boot is the startup of `system-networkd`, which fails with the message ("Operation not supported"). Closer examination reveals that `systemd-networkd` tries to run as a user (`system-network`). Since `system-netwworkd` doesn't start, neither do a number of other services:

```
  UNIT                      LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION                   
● atd.service               loaded failed failed Deferred execution scheduler  
● avahi-daemon.service      loaded failed failed Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack       
● systemd-networkd.service  loaded failed failed Network Service               
● systemd-resolved.service  loaded failed failed Network Name Resolution       
● systemd-timesyncd.service loaded failed failed Network Time Synchronization  
● systemd-networkd.socket   loaded failed failed Network Service Netlink Socket

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.

6 loaded units listed.
```

## Configuration

### DHCPd

I have a pair of ISC DHCP servers which have been running well for over a year. I made the following alterations to their configuration to support network booting:

```
# DHCP configuration for PXE boot of RPI4

option tftp-server-name "192.168.8.20"; #option 66
option bootfile-name "bootcode.bin"; #option 67

option vendor-class-identifier code 60 = string;
option vendor-encapsulated-options code 43 = string;
option space RPi code width 1 length width 1;
option RPi.discovery code 6 = unsigned integer 8;
option RPi.menu-prompt code 10 = text;
option RPi.menu-item code 9 = text;

option vendor-class-identifier "PXEClient";
option vendor-encapsulated-options "Raspberry Pi Boot";
vendor-option-space RPi;
option RPi.discovery 3;
option RPi.menu-prompt "PXE";
option RPi.menu-item "Raspberry Pi Boot";

filename "pxelinux.0";

next-server 192.168.8.20;
option tftp-server-address 192.168.8.20;
```

I will admit that I don't entirely understand this, but it works :-) I'm sure there's stuff in there that the RPi4 doesn't use.

### Raspberry Pi 4b

I have set up the RPi4 boot loader as follows:

```
$ sudo rpi-eeprom-config 
[all]
BOOT_UART=0
WAKE_ON_GPIO=1
POWER_OFF_ON_HALT=1
BOOT_ORDER=0xf21
TFTP_PREFIX=1
TFTP_PREFIX_STR=RPi4-Ubuntu/
```

### Synology DS 1618+ NAS

#### TFTP Server

At startup the RPi4 sends the `TFTP_PREFIX_STR` above and receives the following files back from the TFTP server on the Synology NAS:

```
bcm2710-rpi-2-b.dtb       bootcode.bin  initrd.img
bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb       boot.scr      overlay_map.dtb
bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb  cmdline.txt   overlays
bcm2710-rpi-cm3.dtb       config.txt    start4cd.elf
bcm2710-rpi-zero-2.dtb    fixup4cd.dat  start4db.elf
bcm2711-rpi-400.dtb       fixup4.dat    start4.elf
bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb       fixup4db.dat  start4x.elf
bcm2711-rpi-cm4.dtb       fixup4x.dat   start_cd.elf
bcm2837-rpi-3-a-plus.dtb  fixup_cd.dat  start_db.elf
bcm2837-rpi-3-b.dtb       fixup.dat     start.elf
bcm2837-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb  fixup_db.dat  start_x.elf
bcm2837-rpi-cm3-io3.dtb   fixup_x.dat   vmlinuz
```

These are from the Ubuntu 20.04 installation image for RPi (partition `boot`). I have made the following modifications to `config.txt`:

```
[pi4]
# Run as fast as firmware / board allows
arm_boost=1

[all]
arm_64bit=1
device_tree_address=0x03000000
enable_uart=1
cmdline=cmdline.txt
kernel=vmlinuz
initramfs initrd.img followkernel

include syscfg.txt
include usercfg.txt
```

and `cmdline.txt`:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=192.168.8.20:/volume3/pxe/nfs/RPi4-Ubuntu/OS,tcp,rw ip=dhcp rootfstype=nfs elevator=deadline rootwait
```

#### NFS Server

The NFS server serves up the `nfsroot` mentioned in `cmdline.txt` as the root (`/`). This is basically the `rootfs` partition from the Ubuntu distro. It also serves up the files from the Ubuntu distro's `boot` partition, which are mounted at `/boot`.

`exports -v` shows the following:

```
/volume3/pxe    192.168.0.0/21(rw,async,no_wdelay,hide,crossmnt,no_subtree_check,insecure_locks,anonuid=1024,anongid=100,sec=sys,insecure,root_squash,no_all_squash)
/volume3/pxe    192.168.8.0/21(rw,async,no_wdelay,hide,crossmnt,no_subtree_check,insecure_locks,anonuid=1024,anongid=100,sec=sys,insecure,root_squash,no_all_squash)
/volume3/pxe    192.168.32.0/21(rw,async,no_wdelay,hide,crossmnt,no_subtree_check,insecure_locks,anonuid=1024,anongid=100,sec=sys,insecure,root_squash,no_all_squash)
/volume3/pxe    192.168.72.0/21(rw,async,no_wdelay,hide,crossmnt,no_subtree_check,insecure_locks,anonuid=1024,anongid=100,sec=sys,insecure,root_squash,no_all_squash)
```

During the boot process, it seems that Synology NFS and the RPi4 will only use NFSv3. In `/etc/fstab`, however, they both seem happy to use NFSv4/NFSv4.1.

#### Back to the Pi

With this constellation the RPi boots and runs well over the net with an NFS file system as root. However, at this point, wishing to protect the root file system from being written to, I proceed to modify the configuration file of `overlayroot` at `/etc/overlayroot.conf` so it looks like the following:

```
overlayroot_cfgdisk="disabled"
#overlayroot=""
overlayroot="tmpfs:recurse=0,debug=1"
```

(I have omitted the 160+ lines of comment before this.)

When I reboot the problem described above ensues.

## Help! Please?

I have tried the above with 32-bit and 64-bit Ubuntu 22.04 with exactly the same result. I tried Raspberry OS 11 (64-bit), but it doesn't offer `overlayroot` as an option. Its alternative, built into `raspi-config`, doesn't work with NFS. So I didn't pursue that.

I greatly simplified the TFTP configuration for Ubuntu, however, based on what Raspberry OS does.

I wouldn't be surprised if the problem had something to do with the Synology NFS server, but I don't really know where to start looking.

I certainly don't preclude the idea that I have made a mistake somewhere, so I'd be grateful if anyone could point any such out.

As soon as Ubuntu 22.04 comes out, I'll try that too.

There are lots of people out in the Net who have talked about doing this. I've read a lot of articles and tried to take their messages onboard. I've seen one or two allusions to possible problems with NFS root file systems and `overlayroot`. But I've not seen anything that describes exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because question was cross-posted on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: It might be a better idea to close the original post on Ask Ubuntu, because there seems to be more action here.

Comment: As the person who posted the questions, you're able to close/delete any for reasons you choose. The community can only vote/suggest, and it requires several of us to agree before an action is taken.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I cross-posted here because Ask Ubuntu produced no useful reaction. I'm not sure what the etiquette is in such situations. Perhaps I should go and close the Ask Ubuntu thread?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is relatively simple, though it took a long time to find it.

If you netboot Ubuntu with NFS on an RPi4 the `nfsmount` included with `klibc` (as delivered by Ubuntu) only supports NFS v2 and v3. If you [replace](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/klibc/+bug/1954716/comments/24) that `nfsmount` with one that supports NFSv4 and your root filesystem is successfully mounted by NFSv4, `overlayroot` works as it is supposed to.

Spoiler: it is an upstream (i.e. Debian) [bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=409272) that has been around since 2007. Repeat: 2007.

Comment: This is a copy of the answer I gave to a similar [question on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1401854/why-doesnt-overlayroot-work-properly-with-a-net-booted-nfs-root-on-a-rpi4).

Comment: So I ended up here with very similar symptoms. Thanks @Stephen Winnall for such a nice writeup. Just like what you were seeing, disabling `overlayroot` fixes things, and with `overlayroot` only `root` can login, etc. The extra interesting wrinkle is that this issue only happens when the NFS share is on a TrueNAS machine. With the NFS share on an Ubuntu box, `overlayroot` works just fine. Do you have any insight into why overlayroot has issues when NFS v2/v3 are used?

Comment: @aggieNick02 Sorry, I was fixated on making NFSv4 work. I remember reading something about ACLs, but I couldn’t get my head round it :-)

Comment: Totally get that, I still don't have a full understanding of it either; the whole thing definitely seems scarily brittle. And in different directions too. You fixed your NFSv3 problems by moving to NFSv4.The other person I linked to had no problems with NFSv3, and hit problems when migrating to NFSv4, with the solution being to disable ACL stuff.  Yet what I'm seeing is problems on NFSv3 precisely when ACL stuff is not available. And then NFSv2, which has no optional ACL stuff at all, worked fine for me. It definitely doesn't inspire confidence. ;-)

Comment: I did  look at the source of the `nfsmount` that was delivered with Ubuntu. It was a jumble of alternative actions depending on the version of NFS (<=3) in use. I just replaced it with a shell script that took the same arguments and then called them with `mount -t nfs`. The choice of NFSv4 is dictated by the arguments passed to my `nfsmount`. If it were passed a request for NFSv2 or NFSv3 it would at least try to respect that, but I have never tried it. Your symptoms might be down to `nfsmount` doing something weird. Why would `nfsmount` need to do anything different depending on NFS version?

Comment: Interesting. It's also worth noting that my reproduction steps for recreating the issue with v3 noacl were with just calling `mount`, so it isn't just `nfsmount` that is affected/involved in the issue.

Comment: So perhaps there IS something in some forgotten corner of `nfsmount` which will make it work for you if you find the right trigger? Perhaps it’s just a question of the proper kernel boot parameters? That’s the talk: sadly, I can’t walk it…

Answer (score 0):

Copied from the same question over at askubuntu:

The root issue appears to be that `overlayfs` behaves incorrectly in certain NFS server configurations. Namely, something goes awry when `overlayfs` is used on top of an NFSv3 export on a server that does not implement [the optional NFSACL protocol extensions for v3](https://lwn.net/Articles/120338/). It looks like this [isn't the only case of `overlayfs` being very brittle with respect to ACLs](https://blog.fai-project.org/posts/overlayfs/). [Apparently there have been (still are?) issues with both v3 and v4 NFS.](https://lkml.org/lkml/2012/9/6/378)

I was able to simplify the problem to one not involving boot, but instead just overlayfs and NFS exports. With an NFS export of an Ubuntu image served from an Ubuntu machine (which does implement NFSACLv3) and a directory named `/tmp/overlaygames/` with empty `upper`,`work`, and `overlay` directories within, the following script would run without error:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo mount -t nfs -o ro,vers=3 10.99.0.1:/srv/nfs/ubuntu-20.04.3 /media/nfs/
sudo mount -t overlay -o lowerdir=/media/nfs,upperdir=/tmp/overlaygames/upper,workdir=/tmp/overlaygames/workdir/ overlay /tmp/overlaygames/overlay
ls /tmp/overlaygames/overlay/home
```

Now after running that, run this script to unmount and cleanup:

```
#!/bin/bash
pushd /tmp/overlaygames
sudo umount overlay
rm -rf workdir
mkdir workdir
sudo umount /media/nfs
popd
```

Now running the exact same script, but disabling NFSACLv3 client side with the noacl option:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo mount -t nfs -o ro,noacl,vers=3 10.99.0.1:/srv/nfs/ubuntu-20.04.3 /media/nfs/
sudo mount -t overlay -o lowerdir=/media/nfs,upperdir=/tmp/overlaygames/upper,workdir=/tmp/overlaygames/workdir/ overlay /tmp/overlaygames/overlay
ls /tmp/overlaygames/overlay/home
```

will return the familiar

```
ls: cannot open directory '/tmp/overlaygames/overlay/home': Operation not supported
```

Likewise, starting with the first script but putting the NFS export on a FreeNAS/TrueNAS (FreeBSD) machine, will also return `Operation not supported` because FreeBSD does not implement NFSACLv3 (verified by capturing packets).

Interestingly, specifying `vers=2` when working with an NFS share on FreeBSD appears to work just fine. Granted, NFSv2 has some limitations compared to NFSv3.

Comment: Interesting. As I said in my answer, I fixed it by making NFS boot work for NFSv4: see https://github.com/winnall/rpi4-ubuntu-nfsv4-boot-hack .